# Determining orbits and stabilisers

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is given that $$(x,y) \cdot \left [\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
b & a \end{array}\right] =(ax+by,bx+ay)$$
defines an action on the group 
$$G=\left\{\left [\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
b & a \end{array}\right]:a^2 \neq b^2\right\}$$

1) Determine the orbits
2) Determine the stabilisers of (0,0),(1,0),(1,1)

How do I do this?

Comment: Orbits.  You have have essentially written the answer down,   For a fixed $(x,y),$   you generate new points $(x,y)  \cdot A,$ where $A \in G.$   Can you reach any point $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ using some particular $A.$    For the stabilisers, use the definition. e.g.  find all $A\in G$ such that $(1,1)A=(1,1).$   This gives you equations $(a+b,a+b)=(1,1).$   You should work out what subgroup of $G$ this generates.

Comment: So you just use the definitions to get $(1,0)=(a,b)$ and $(0,0)=(0,0)$ But in my notes I have also (1,-1). Why? Also why do we need the subgroups?

Answer (score 0):

Given a (right) group action by $G$ on a set $S,$ and a point $x\in S,$ the *Stabilizer at $x$ is*  is the subgroup of $G$ defined as follows:  $$G_x = \{g \in G \ : \ xg=x\}.$$ 
For your group action, with $A= \left[\begin{array}{cc} a& b \\ b & a \end{array}\right]\in G,$ you have $(1,0)A = (1,0)$ if and only if $a-1=0$ and $b=0.$  Thus 
$$
G_{(1,0)} = \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] \right\}.
$$
Similarly, we have $(1,1)A=(1,1)$ if and only if $a+b=1.$  Therefore, 
$$
G_{(1,1)} =  \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & 1-a \\ 1-a & a \end{array} \right]  \ : \ a \neq 1 \right\}.
$$ 
You should verify for yourself that $G_{(0,0)}= G.$